# How to filter the file types in primeng p-fileupload component

Tags: java, angular, file-upload, primeng

I am trying to filter the file dialogue window using p-fileUpload from primeng.
I saw an example to to filter images as image/* and it works but i want ti filter for excel files. I tried file/excel, file/*.xls etc, but no help. Need help.

Comment: Please c.f. [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for good questions that get good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below inputs with **accept** property in **p-fileUpload** in Angular

1. Image filter 
   `accept="image/*"`[accepts all image file types] 
   `accept="image/*.jpeg"`[accepts only JPEG image file types]
2. File filter 
   `accept="application/msexcel"` [accepts only xls file types]
   `accept=".xlsm,application/msexcel"` [accepts only xls & xlsm file types]
   `accept="application/msmsword"` [accepts only word file types]

Comment: Aditional to this response take in mind that if you wish especify multiples types that be write without any space something like this:

Image filter
accept=".jpg,.png,.gif"

Answer (score 11):

we can filter by required type like this

```
accept=".xlsx,.pdf,.csv,.xls"
```

Answer (score 3):

**.html**

```
<p-fileUpload accept="{{acceptedFiles}}" invalidFileTypeMessageDetail="Sólo se permiten ficheros {{acceptedFiles}}"></p-fileUpload>
```

**.ts**

```
 acceptedFiles: string = ".pdf, .jpg, .png, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .csv";
```